# javascript regexp get no quotes params

Tags: javascript, regex, literals

eg:

```
var str = '2+3+name+"obj.name name"+"g233"';
```

how can i get the "variable values"/"object properties" within str in place "obj.name name" and "g233" strings

---

the example **output comment** below is what i want, if there has a best way to realize it;

```js
var age = 20;
var str = '1 + 2 + 3 + age + "age"'; 

// the output is 1 + 2 + 3 + 20 + "age";

var obj = { age: 30 };
str = '1 + 2 + 3 + "age" + obj.age + "obj.age"';

// the output is 1 + 2 + 3 + "age" + 30 + "obj.age";
```

the exmple is what i want.

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? do you have a few more examples?

Comment: @DanielCheng sorry, i just edit the question and has example in it; please help! – kelen 27 secs ago    edit

Comment: Are there only `+` operations?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it's not the point, if it can use regex to get the params, the other operation i can realize it

Comment: You need to provide better examples: Write down the input string and the matched output string. We don't know if e.g. age is a number like `23` or if is the string `age`.

Comment: What's your use case for this?

Comment: @melpomene the use case is in the question!

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 the use case is in the question!

Comment: That's not a use case. Assume you had a function that did this. What would you do with it?

Answer (score -1):

You can search for the following regular expression, if you want to match `obj.age` or `age` without surrounding `"`.

```
[^"](obj\.age|age)[^"]
```

```js
var str1 = '1 + 2 + 3 + age + "age"'; 
var str2 = '1 + 2 + 3 + "age" + obj.age + "obj.age"';
var regex = /[^"](obj\.age|age)[^"]/g;

console.log(str1.match(regex));
console.log(str2.match(regex));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this link if you need regexp

https://regex101.com/r/DTTesL/1

If yoy want to ES2015 / ES6 feature called Template Literals use this syntax:

```
`String text ${expression}`
```

You even can make it like this:

```
'I want to replace the $age'.replace('$age', age)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/(?:^|\+)\s*([a-z_][\w.]*)\s*($|\+)/gi
```

this will match any variable that is right at the beginig (`^`) or after a `+` sign, and before the end (`$`) or another plus sign `+`. `[a-z_][\w.]*` means that it have to start with a letter or `_` and can contain numbers, letters, `_` and `.`.

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var regex = /(?:^|\+)\s*([a-z_][\w.]*)\s*(?:\+|$)/g;

var str = '1+name + obj.ko + "lmo" + f98 + "g99"+v';

var matches = [];
var r;
while(r = regex.exec(str)){
    // should come backwards one step to cover the just-consumed +
    regex.lastIndex--;
    matches.push(r[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: False positives: `foo + "+bar+"`

Comment: @melpomene Then he's screwed. As then, it will not be a regular text, so regular expressions won't work.